# adding data to fusion tables using an url in a browser

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have been trying to read/write from/to a fusion table directly from my browser using different urls. For Reading a use "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT * FROM  WHERE ID = '1' &key=" This works well and i can read data in Json.
For inserting data i use "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=INSERT INTO  (ID, Adress) VALUES (1, 'Prästkragsvägen 33') &key=" In this case i get the following error:
    "domain": "fusiontables",
    "reason": "cannotWriteDataOnGetRequests",
    "message": "The operation is not supported for GET requests.  Please try again using POST."
  "code": 501

The table is set to public. How should the url for an INSERT command look like?

Regards

Alfred

Answer (score 1):

For inserts and updates into fusiontable you will need POST requests. Your browser's address bar only does get requests. 
You could try console with jquery $.ajax or curl in a terminal